# Creating custom table cell content on React FixedDataTable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fixed-data-table

I'm new to React and I'm studying how to use for building an extensive logger. We thought of this framework because we'll have plenty content to show, and we need it to be responsive and dynamic. One of the requirements is inserting custom cell content, like unsorted lists, or a couple of images in a single cell.

I'm having some issues figuring out how that's done. Placing simple content, like text, is easy, of course, but when I try to insert a list all falls down to pieces. Right now, I'm doing some tests on FixedDataTable, as it seemed to be the one with the most customization. The problem is that setting row content is easy, I just need to supply an array of values, but I have no idea how to turn a single cell into something else. I tried creating the  by hand or even giving it the plain HTML, the first option does not work (I get a div with an [Object object] instead) and the second just writes the tags on the cell.

Could someone please provide an example on how to do this? Right now, I'm not stuck to any framework, but we do want something based on React, and any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the section "Create Reusable Cells" at http://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/getting-started.html

It encourages to use Cell API now.

Comment: That will do! Thanks very much!

Comment: Done :) Sorry, it was my first post om Stack Overflow, I'm not used to the routine